# Grouped tile / gridview in Android

Tags: android, gridview, tile

what I want to do in my app is some sort of grouped tileview / gridview.
There should be one header tile for each group an under that the included child tiles. This should be dynamical so there could be zero, one or multiple groups and every group have at least one element. Between the groupes there should be a bit of space. Every groupheader and every tile should be clickable.
This image make it clear what I mean.

[image]

I was thinking about to make two GridViews and use them like fragments but I think there is a better way to do that. So what would be the best way?
And does anybody know if this would be also possible to do in iOS or are there going to be any problems with the guidlines?